# Why the $L$ in an $RLC$ circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, terminology, notation, inductance

I was studying for a differential equations class and came upon some information about $RLC$ circuits. I know the $R$ stands for resistance (makes sense) and $C$ stands for capacitor (this also makes sense to me). So why does $L$ stand for the inductor, as opposed to the letter $I$ (or any other letter)?

After some preliminary searches, all I could turn up was that $L$ stood for the inductance (roughly speaking). I noticed the units here were "henrys" so I thought it might be related to the name of the person that the units were named for, but this turned up Joseph Henry. Alas, I'm left wondering...

> Why is the letter $L$ used to represent an inductor in $RLC$ circuits?

Comment: Also with the below answer, $I$ is already used for current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance)

> "It is customary to use the symbol $L$ for inductance, in honour of the physicist [Heinrich Lenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Lenz)".